# Class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, compilation, syntax-error

```
/********************************************
//   Problems.java
\\   
//   Provide lots of syntax errors for the user to correct.
\\          
 ********************************************/

public class Problems
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println ("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        System.out.println ("This program still has lots of problems,");
        System.out.print ("but" + "," + " if it prints this, you fixed them all.");
        System.out.println ("             *** Hurray! ***");
        System.out.println ("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

I'm quite new here and am wondering what is wrong with the code. All it does is show text, but when I compile it, I get an error "Class, interface, or enum expected".

It says there's something wrong with the last line (where the last `}` is). I'm not sure what is wrong here.

This assignment is for my computer science class. We were supposed to fix a few syntax errors (I do have bad eyes, so I might have not seen things like semicolons) and compile it and run, but it won't compile.

I was using JCreator 4.5 for this. I also tried compiling it at school and with a DOS prompt. HELP!

Comment: How are u compiling it? I am able to compile it wihtou problems

Comment: Use an IDE like eclipse, intellij, or netbeans. There is no point doing this with your eyes when you have all these tools available.

Comment: I've also tried using a DOS prompt to compile it (via javac) and it gives the same message.

Comment: Your first problem is that you're using JCreator.

Comment: @arshajii my teacher doesn't want us to use any other IDE lol

Comment: @user2813219 You don't have to use the IDE for them. Use it for yourself.

Comment: @user2813219 I figured that; JCreator is popular among teachers (probably because it's so primitive). However, I urge you to at least look at Eclipse (my favorite) and perhaps Netbeans, as SotiriosDelimanolis pointed out.

Comment: Is this entire code in your `Problems.java` file? Is it in `Problems.java` file? Did you save your file after you corrected mistakes and tried to compile it?

Comment: @Pshemo this is legitimately the file

Comment: @JunedAhsan Tell me how you compiled it :(

Comment: @user2813219 Arshajii is right could be a problem with JCreator. I in fact ran your code without any issues using eclipse.

Comment: @Khush What about DOS? I have the newest JDK. DOS shouldn't lie!

Comment: Please post the complete error message you're getting. And you're using a command prompt, but it's not DOS; DOS finally died with Windows ME. You can call it `cmd` if you like.

Comment: @chrylis Class names, 'Problems', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested (according to the DOS/cmd prompt)

"Class, interface, or enum expected" (according to Jcreator)

Comment: @chrylis just so used to my teacher saying DOS prompt lol

Comment: @user2813219 Have you got anything outside the class declaration?? Check the Problems.java file once again and see if there is nothing outside the class parenthesis.

Comment: @Khush Dumb it down, please :(

Comment: @user2813219 make sure nothing is declared outside your class parenthesis OR Curly braces - {}. Everything declared should be within these parenthesis. Except for imports. So check this.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error you provided

> 'Problems', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested (according to the DOS/cmd prompt)

your command line arguments may be wrong, there is a post about this error in the following article

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/

The exact qoute being

> Class names, 'HelloWorldApp', are only accepted if annotation
>   processing is explicitly requested
>
> If you receive this error, you forgot to include the .java suffix when
>   compiling the program. Remember, the command is javac
>   HelloWorldApp.java not javac HelloWorldApp.

Comment: lol that error. Regardless, I still get the same "Class, interface, enum" error.

Comment: @user2813219 I really hesitate to ask this, but can you post a screenshot of your `cmd` window?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I compile your code. Try to recreate my steps and say if you get any errors.

---

Since this class is not in any specific package I created `Problems.java` file in `d:\java tests`. This file contains

```
/********************************************
//Problems.java
\\   
//Provide lots of syntax errors for the user to correct.
\\          
********************************************/


public class Problems
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println ("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        System.out.println (" This program still has lots of problems,");
        System.out.println ("but" + "," + " if it prints this, you fixed them all.");
        System.out.println ("             *** Hurray! ***");
        System.out.println ("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

I used UTF-8 coding.

Next in console I went to `d:\java tests>` and from this directory I used

```
d:\java tests>javac Problems.java
```

(you need to add `.java` suffix in class name here) which successfully created `Problems.class` file. To run main method from this class I used

```
d:\java tests>java Problems
```

(no suffixes here) which printed

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 This program still has lots of problems,
but, if it prints this, you fixed them all.
             *** Hurray! ***
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: +1 for step-by-step, which will hopefully helps other beginners. Half the battle is the environment. P.S. your 50 bounty netted 120 rep :)

Comment: @Bohemian np :) now I am among SO investors and altruists :D

Comment: Basically what I did in the end: I recreated the program. Tedious and will not work in larger projects, but thank you for giving the closest answer.

Comment: I didn't add the ln, though. (in the 3rd System.out.println)

Comment: @user2813219 `ln` doesn't matter, added just for nicer output.

Comment: @user2813219 Since you accepted my answer I assume that it worked for you. If reason for solving your problem was adding `.java` suffix in `>javac Problems.java` command then you probably should accept *Alan's* answer since he pointed it first.

Comment: @user2813219 Is this the same error? If yes then there is no need to accept any answer that doesn't fully solve your problem.

Comment: @Pshemo I'll just let my teacher deal with it, then. The code in this is practically the same and other people compiled my code correctly.

Comment: @user2813219 your code is OK now so you should be fine. Although I am little curios why you cant compile it...